# Using jna.jar: Missing manifest attributes

Tags: java, jar, applet, jna

I'm working on an applet that uses jna-4.0.0.jar. In the Java Console I'm getting this:

Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: .../jna-4.0.0.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: .../jna-4.0.0.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: .../jna-4.0.0.jar

I haven't found a version of jna.jar in which these manifest attributes are set. Is there any?

How can I add these attributes to the manifest?

Though it's working yet I need to fix this.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation, complete with a workaround [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml)

> Steps to Add URL to the Exception Site list: Go to the Java Control
>   Panel (On Windows Click Start and then Configure Java), Click on the
>   Security tab, Click on the Edit Site List button, Click the Add in the
>   Exception Site List window